# How to use nested object destructoring in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, telegram-bot, telegraf

As noob in the typescript, trying to use nested object destructure with custom variable name. Unfortunately, the still getting error message which says property does not exist.

[image]

Current code

```
export interface Message {
  message_id?:       number;
  from?:             From;
  chat?:             Chat;
  date?:             number;
  reply_to_message?: ReplyToMessage;
  text?:             string;
  entities?:         Entity[];
}

export interface Chat {
  id?:                             number;
  title?:                          string;
  type?:                           string;
  all_members_are_administrators?: boolean;
}

export interface Entity {
  offset?: number;
  length?: number;
  type?:   string;
}

export interface From {
  id?:            number;
  is_bot?:        boolean;
  first_name?:    string;
  username?:      string;
  language_code?: string;
  last_name?:     string;
}

export interface ReplyToMessage {
  message_id?: number;
  from?:       From;
  chat?:       Chat;
  date?:       number;
  text?:       string;
}

const banUser = async ( ctx: Context, next: NextFunction) => {
  const {
    from: { id: userId },
  } : Message = ctx.message || {};

  // console.log('userId ', id);
  console.log('userId ', userId);
  console.log('chatId ', chatId);
});
```

The object structure would be look like this

```
{
  message_id: 316,
  from: {
    id: 09328434,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'Me',
    username: 'hellomate',
    language_code: 'en'
  },
  chat: {
    id: -864382326,
    title: 'testging me',
    type: 'group',
    all_members_are_administrators: true
  },
  date: 1664828834,
  reply_to_message: {
    message_id: 298,
    from: {
      id: 151956245,
      is_bot: false,
      first_name: 'its',
      last_name: 'me',
      username: 'itsme',
      language_code: 'en'
    },
    chat: {
      sweetmaanu
      title: 'testging me',
      type: 'group',
      all_members_are_administrators: true
    },
    date: 1664827579,
    text: 'sldfkvherolit'
  },
  text: '/start',
  entities: [ { offset: 0, length: 6, type: 'bot_command' } ]
}
```

Comment: It would seem to bypass the usefulness of types if every single property is optional.

Comment: @James On the contrary, that's why types are used: to document that every property can be optional. However, the way they are used here is questionable and may not reflect the actual structure of the object at runtime...

Comment: Sure.  But instead of relying on MyType.id to be an integer, everywhere I use it I have to check if it's defined first.  Ugh.

Comment: @james made all types are optional for testing purpose only

Answer (score 1):

Give it a default value since it can be undefined:

```
const {
  from: { id: userId } = {},
  chat: { id: chatId } = {},
} : Message = ctx.message || {};
```